# Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\registerController does not exist in laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

I can't understand what is happening here. on my local server its working fine but when I put everything on my live server I'm having this error

[image]

My web Route

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]); 

Route::get('/', function(){ 
    return view('auth.login'); 
})->name('auth.login')->middleware('auth'); 

Route::resource('/register', 'Auth\registerController@index')->name('register');

Route::group( ['middleware' => 'auth' ], function()
{   
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');   
    Route::group(['namespace' => 'dashboard', 'prefix' => 'dashboard'], function() {
        Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index');
    });

    SO ON...
}
```

My RegisterController

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{  
    use RegistersUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');       
    }

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $referral = '';
        $keyword = $request->get('search');
        $referral = Referral::where([
                         ['code', $keyword],
                         ['status', 0]
                         ])->first();        

        if (is_null($keyword))
            return view ( 'Auth.register');
        elseif ($referral)
            return view ( 'Auth.register', compact('referral', $referral))
                                    ->withDetails ( $referral )
                                    ->withQuery ( $keyword );
        else 
            return view ( 'Auth.register')->withMessage ( 'The code you provided is not existing or already been taken.' );
    } 

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'country_code' => $data['country_code'],
            'phone_number' => $data['phone_number'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

registerController Path

[image]

what do you this causing this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: change `registerController` to `RegisterController`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this line of code in your web.php file is causing the issue

```
Route::resource('/register', 'Auth\registerController@index')->name('register');
```

your class name starts with `R` but you have written using `r`. moreover it seems the route is a simple get route but you have written it as resource. change this too. so the route should be like

```
Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@index')->name('register');
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you namespace your registerController?

Because laravel later versions use a rather different namespace than previous versions. Hence change your namespace (and imported files) to this;

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using laravel 8:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController;
    Auth::routes(['register' => false]);
    Route::get('/user_register', [RegisterController::class, 'showRegistrationForm'])->name('register');
```

However it throws this error when I clean cache:

```
 Unable to prepare route [user_register] for serialization. Another route has already been assigned name [register].
```

The new route works, but the old route yet it works

Comment: changue: ->name('register') to ->name('register2') but the register route is yet visible